# How to fix sub-query in LEFT JOIN in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried to add in JOIN sub-query:

```
    $this->db->join('stocks AS stn', 'stn.stocksIdMF = 
    (SELECT medicalfacilities.MedicalFacilitiesIdUser 
            FROM medicalfacilities 
            WHERE medicalfacilities.MedicalFacilitiesIdUser = stn.stocksIdMF AND stn.stocksEndDate >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
        ORDER BY stn.stocksId DESC LIMIT 1)',
'LEFT', false);'
```

But Codeigniter spoils this query. What is wrong in query?
May be somehow replace this query?

Comment: can you show us the whole query statement?

Comment: `stn` is not recognized at your subquery. also your join query is not right.what does 4th parameter `false` do?